# Do there exist other tricks for trig with Cauchy's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have noticed that $$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$ with $|b|<|a|$

Are there any other tricks like this for say $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{a+b\sin\theta}$?

Comment: The answer to your more general question is yes, there are lots of examples. The answer to your more specific question is that $\sin$ takes the same values as $\cos$ over the interval $[0,2\pi]$, so the two integrals you have written evaluate to the same value.

Comment: @user319635 It can be done with High School Calculus and some slick trigonometry. I think you can find various approaches even here on MSE.

Comment: On a side note, I edited, because inside the radical it has to be $a^2-b^2$, not $b^2+a^2$, and there is a restriction that $b$ must be smaller than $a$ (in absolute terms). Do you see why?

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to use contour integration to evaluate the integral of interest, then one simply enforces the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$.  Thus, $\cos (\theta)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$, $d\theta =\frac{1}{iz}\,dz$ and we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{a+b\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\,\left(\frac{1}{iz}\right)\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{2}{ib}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{\left(z+(a/b)+\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)\left(z+(a/b)-\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)}\,dz \tag 1\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{2}{ib}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}}\right) \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

**NOTE:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we applied the Residue Theorem.  Note that in proceeding, we recognizing that for $|a|>|b|$, the only pole inside $|z|=1$ is at $z=-(a/b)+\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the periodicity of $\cos$, the integrand is periodic with period $2\pi$, so the following integrals integrate over a whole period and thus have the same value.
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a + b\cos\theta} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a + b\cos(\theta - \theta_0)}
$$
Now substitute something for $\theta_0$ to change it to $\sin$.